Find function by name in a complex object using dev tools
I'm importing a library in a project and I can't find a method that I'm supposed to use.
The functions name is itDoesntMatterFunctionName().
Is there a search by function name in the chrome debugger tools that if I give it an object it will find it?
Example:
var myApp = new ComplexApplication();
console.find(myApp, "myFunctionName");

It's entirely possible that this function is not exported by the module because note this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './lib/pixi/pixi.mjs' does not provide an export named 'getCanvasBoundingBox'

But it does find other classes / objects in the module.
Chrome debugger / Dev tools Filter box (does not find methods or properties on objects which is what I want):

The Javascript pseudocode for this would be something like:
var object = window.document;
var searchString = "body";
// loop through all objects and property names on the object
while (object typeof object) {
    if (object[searchString]!==undefined) {
        // return object path
    }
    // loop through all properties on object recursively
}

This is not a duplicate. This is asking how to do this with Dev Tools. Since dev tools don't support this the correct answer is "no" not the closure of the question.

Are you sure that's coming from console.find()? I suspect it's from new ComplexApplication() and unrelated to searching for the method.

Wouldn't it be easier to do this by searching the source code, rather than in the browser? Most IDEs provide tools to search for something in all the files in a directory.

@Barmar I wrote a pseudo method in the example code, console.find(). I don't think it exists. The ComplexApplication is simply any object. The dev tools do have a find box.

@Barmar the library has the method in it but I don't see any exports (so the error could be accurate) so I was guessing that maybe the function is a class member but I can't find where.

Here's the function, https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/blob/dev/src/utils/canvas/getCanvasBoundingBox.ts but the question is mainly to see if the chrome debug dev tools has the ability to find a function given an object

AFAIK, console.find() just does the same thing that Ctrl-f does by hand in the Sources tab. I don't think it runs any of the code, it's just searching for the text in the files that are already loaded.

@Barmar I console.find() method is made up. I'm using it as an example. It doesn't exist.

Oops, Google AI hallucinated the function when I was searching for it....

I think the answer to your basic question is no. I don't think there are functions for searching in objects or classes. In the Sources panel you can search for text, similar to a text editor.

@Barmar it might have. it might exist in some environments but I don't see it in chrome debug tools. I added the possible javascript equivalent pseudocode into the question. basically, "here is an object. find if it or any of it's descendants have this specific member."

I don't think so either. I tried to use JSON.stringify(object) and then pass that string into a text file and then search that string manually but the parser errors out. JSON.stringify(app.stage) VM1958:1 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON     --> starting at object with constructor '_Transform'     |     property 'position' -> object with constructor 'ObservablePoint'     --- property 'scope' closes the circle     at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

JSON.stringify doesn't contain methods that come from the prototype.

And JSON can't include functions.

also the duplicate question is asking about a property value not a property name

Are you looking to traverse an object recursively looking for a specific key?


function findKey(obj, key, currentPath, visited) {
  if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return
  }

  // prevent circular stuff
  visited = visited || []
  if (visited.includes(obj)) {
    return
  }
  visited.push(obj)

  currentPath = currentPath || []

  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      findKey(obj[i], key, currentPath.concat(i), visited);
    }
  } else {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(prop => {
      const newPath = currentPath.concat(prop);
      if (prop === key) {
        console.log(newPath.join("."));
      }
      findKey(obj[prop], key, newPath, visited);
    });
  }
}

var noop = () => {}

var obj = {
  this: [{
    foo: noop
  }, {
    func: noop
  }],
  that: {
    another: 1,
    foo: noop
  }
}
obj.self = obj

findKey(obj, 'foo')




in my personal libraries i call this an apiExplorer and it goes something like this, its fairly primitive and could do with going to version 2, any help would be great, for instance it doesnt check for circular references


function apiexplorer(mod, maxdepth, name) {

  maxdepth = maxdepth || 2;
  var list = [];

  var o = gen(mod, '', 0);
  if (o) {
    return o;
  }
  return list;

  function gen(mod, pre, depth) {

    if (depth === maxdepth) {
      return;
    }

    for (var key in mod) {

      var o = mod[key];

      if (name === key) {
        return o;
      }

      var type = typename(o);

      if (pre) {
        key = pre + '.' + key;
      }

      if (key === name) {
        return o;
      }

      add(key, type);

      if (!isprimitive(o)) {
        var o = gen(o, key, depth + 1);
        if (o) {
          return o;
        }
      }

    } //for

  } //gen


  function add(key, type) {

    var o1 = {
      key,
      type
    };
    var n = list.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

      var o = list[i];
      if (o.key > key) {
        list.splice(i, 0, o1);
        return;
      }

    } //for
    list.push(o1);

  } //add


  function isprimitive(v) {

    switch (typeof v) {

      case 'null':
      case 'undefined':
      case 'number':
      case 'string':
      case 'boolean':
        return true;

    } //switch

    return false;

  } //isprimitive


  function typename(v) {

    var str = Object.prototype.toString.call(v);
    var i = str.indexOf(' ');
    str = str.slice(i + 1, -1);
    return str;

  } //typename

} //apiexplorer


//  test

var mod = {
  fn: () => {},
  fn2: () => {},
  test: {
    fn3: () => {},
    fn4: () => {}
  }
};

var name = 'fn3';

var list = apiexplorer(mod, 2, 'fn3');
console.log(name, 'exists', !!list);

var list = apiexplorer(mod, 2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(list, null, 4));



if the function does actually exists and you want to find where it is or look at etc, you can then do
debugger;

mod.test.fn3();

and step into it for instance
